# Android exception: Runtime exception on launching login activity

Tags: android

I'm an android newbie. I'm using the android studio and connecting to a device, 4.04, api 14. I created a default login activity. It throws up the following exception:

```
Launching application: com.noatta.www.noatta_14/com.noatta.www.noatta_14.LoginActivity.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -n "com.noatta.www.noatta_14/com.noatta.www.noatta_14.LoginActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.noatta.www.noatta_14/.LoginActivity }
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.noatta.www.noatta_14/.LoginActivity } from null (pid=16079, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10127
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1332)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1286)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1691)
at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:451)
at com.android.commands.am.Am.run(Am.java:107)
at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:80)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.finishInit(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:260)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.noatta.www.noatta_14" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
    <!-- To access Google+ APIs: -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!--
     To retrieve OAuth 2.0 tokens or invalidate tokens to disconnect a user. This disconnect
     option is required to comply with the Google+ Sign-In developer policies
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

    <!-- To retrieve the account name (email) as part of sign-in: -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

</manifest>
```

Anybody have a suggestion on how to prevent the read exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the intent-filter and the exception states you were missing the `android:exported="true"` in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
       android:name=".LoginActivity"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" 
       android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing `<intent-filter>` in activity definition:

```
<activity
    android:name=".LoginActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```